# Trying to predict the next number in cyphertext using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am experimenting with machine learning and I wanted to see how difficult it would be to predict a number given a series of other numbers. I have seen it accomplished with people making vectors such as 1-10. However, I wanted to try to do something more difficult. I wanted to do it based on the ciphertext. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Lambda, SimpleRNN
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from numpy.polynomial import polynomial as poly
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

import Pyfhel

def generateInput(x, length):
    return np.append(x, [0 for i in range(length)], axis=0)

def main():

    HE = Pyfhel.Pyfhel()
    HE.contextGen(scheme='BFV', n=2048,  q=34, t=34, t_bits=35, sec=128)
    HE.keyGen()
    a = "Hello"
    a = np.asarray(bytearray(a, "utf-8"))
    a = HE.encode(a)
    ct = HE.encrypt(a).to_bytes('none')
    ct = np.asarray([c for c in ct])

    length = 100 # How many records to take into account
    batch_size = 1
    n_features = 1
    epochs = 1
    generator = TimeseriesGenerator(ct, ct, stride=length, length=length, batch_size=batch_size)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(SimpleRNN(100, activation='leaky_relu', input_shape=(length, n_features)))
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='leaky_relu', input_shape=(length, n_features)))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])
    history = model.fit(generator, epochs=epochs)


    for i in range(1, length):
        try:
            x_input = np.asarray(generateInput(ct[:i], length-len(ct[:i]))).reshape((1, length))
            yhat = model.predict(x_input).tolist()
            yhat_normalized = [float(i)/sum(yhat[0]) for i in yhat[0]]
            yhat_max = max(yhat_normalized)
            yhat_index = yhat_normalized.index(yhat_max)

            print("based on {} actual {} predicted {}".format(ct[:i], ct[i], yhat_index))
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error {}".format(e))
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Now the problem is that all of my predictions are 0. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening? How can I fix this?

Here's what my current output looks like:

```
based on [94] actual 161 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161] actual 16 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16] actual 3 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3] actual 7 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0] actual 105 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105] actual 128 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0] actual 78 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78] actual 6 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6] actual 78 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78] actual 65 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65] actual 45 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45] actual 23 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23] actual 12 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12] actual 234 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234] actual 155 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155] actual 45 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45] actual 217 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217] actual 42 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42] actual 230 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230] actual 122 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122] actual 64 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64] actual 99 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99] actual 53 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53] actual 143 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143] actual 104 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104] actual 96 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96] actual 158 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158] actual 146 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0] actual 99 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99] actual 122 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122] actual 217 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217] actual 34 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34] actual 140 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140] actual 238 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238] actual 76 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76] actual 135 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135] actual 237 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0] actual 2 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0] actual 8 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0] actual 1 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0] actual 240 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 240] actual 63 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 240  63] actual 94 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 240  63  94] actual 161 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 240  63  94 161] actual 16 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 240  63  94 161  16] actual 3 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 240  63  94 161  16   3] actual 7 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 240  63  94 161  16   3   7] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 240  63  94 161  16   3   7   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 240  63  94 161  16   3   7   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 240  63  94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0] actual 24 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 240  63  94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0  24] actual 128 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 240  63  94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0  24
 128] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 240  63  94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0  24
 128   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 240  63  94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0  24
 128   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 240  63  94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0  24
 128   0   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 240  63  94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0  24
 128   0   0   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 240  63  94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0  24
 128   0   0   0   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 240  63  94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0  24
 128   0   0   0   0   0   0] actual 0 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 240  63  94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0  24
 128   0   0   0   0   0   0   0] actual 16 predicted 0
based on [ 94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0 105 128   0   0   0   0   0   0  78   6
  78  65  45  23  12 234 155  45 217  42 230 122  64  99  53 143 104  96
 158 146   0  99 122 217  34 140 238  76 135 237   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 240  63  94 161  16   3   7   0   0   0  24
 128   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  16] actual 0 predicted 0
```

Comment: Can you update your question with how your predictions actually look? Since you're using `softmax`, you should have an array of predictions with the same number of elements as classes.

Comment: Are you processing your predictions in any way? The predicted value shouldn't be one number with `softmax`.

Comment: @Djinn how should I be doing this?

Comment: @Djinn If you look at the code I'm calling max and choosing the highest probability value. Then getting its index and assuming that is the number I want

Comment: Don't perform `predict()` in a loop like that. Try doing a batch prediction: load everything into an array then pass that to `predict()`. Prediction performs differently when done in a loop like that, oftentimes getting the same prediction, you probably saw warnings about that. I also think you should step through your for loop and see how the values look. `softmax` produces outputs where the array sums to 1. You shouldn't really be seeing 0 like that.

Comment: @Djinn can you show me how to predict on multiple sets of data at once?

Comment: add to an array as an element each item you want a prediction. use that array as the input for `predict()`